# SQL Stored Procedure all of a sudden expecting parameter which was not supplied

Tags: sql

Really sorry if this is a duplicate, but I can't find my specific problem. I have SQL Server 2012 installed and I have a few Stored Procedures that I call to do various bits and pieces.

A lot of these Stored Procedures have "optional" parameters, well, at least until a few months ago (That I know of). Up until recently (I last tested about 3 or 4 months ago), I was able to call these Stored Procedures and only supply a few of the parameters and they would run perfectly. Now these Stored Procedures are asking for each and every single parameter. I have fixed temporarily by specifying Default values, but I don't want to change all my Stored Procedures.

Does anyone know of any changes MS has done / where I could find a list of changes in respect of this? The weird thing is it worked on both my Dev and Client's Live machine and now both of them don't work?

Any ideas?

Comment: Optional parameters don't need to be supplied, that's why they are optional. Something else must have changed, look for what

Comment: What are you using for a client? As in, what calls the stored procedure?

Comment: Hi,how do I specify the parm as optional (apart from setting a default value). I use VB(6 or .NET) to call the SP, but it's managed by Microsoft's Server Studio Management...